# Right database design pattern when one table is result of processing of other table but processing task is slow

Tags: mysql, sql

There is mysql table ( let's call it `Table_A` ) which contains data about device availability.

Structure of table is simple:

```
device_id | timestamp
```

Data is inserting to table as result of cron script.
If device is available cron script inserts row with `device_id` and current `timestamp` table.

I need to create HTTP REST API which will provide data with periods when devices was busy.

I wrote a script which analyse `Table_A` and return needed data. But problem is that execution time of this script is too long - about 4 minutes for 2 weeks period data. So it's not possible to add this script to API controller.

What can you recommend me do to speed up data processing?

Should I add processing script to cron task, write its output to `Table_B` and add third "flag" field which marks already processed records to `Table_A` ? Is there any other design patterns or common algorithm in such cases ?

Comment: Can you change the way the cron script saves the data. It would be better if you would store the uptimes directly. Wouldn't this be a better table design: `period_id, device_id, start_time, end_time` ? The script would update the end_time if it is not too far in the past, and insert a new period if end_time is not recent.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to change behaviour of INSERT script. So your idea is always store data in format which faster for SELECT than INSERT ?

Comment: If you have too much data to process in real-time you may need to make a summary table that's either periodically compiled, is a materialized `VIEW`, or is updated via either application code or an automatic `TRIGGER`.

Comment: Let's see the "slow processing".  Maybe it can be sped up.  There are _many_ possible optimizations.

Comment: @paulserikov Yes. The insert will only marginally be slower, when defining good indices. You'll have a simple select statement, followed by either an update or an insert.